# Can´t save to directory with Bitmap.Save()

Tags: c#, bitmap, xna

I can´t seem to manage saving a bitmap to a file.

This is my code:

```
FileInfo lInfo = new FileInfo("C:/Content/save/map.png");
Debug.WriteLine(lInfo.FullName);
using (var m = new MemoryStream())
{
     save.Save(m, ImageFormat.Png);
     var img = Image.FromStream(m);
     //TEST
     if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:/Content/save/map.png"))
        img.Save("C:/Content/save/map.png");
     else
        Debug.WriteLine("directory does not exist");
     img.Dispose();
     }
```

save is

```
save = CreateNonIndexedImage(Bitmap.FromFile("Content/save/map.png"));
```

The directory does exist but my code can´t access it.

picture of directory: http://puu.sh/6VLhD.png

Comment: At a guess your user does not have permissions to write to this folder. Normally, UAC will have to be invoked to write to a folder outside of your user area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :**  You are providing file path to the `Directory.Exists()` method.

**Solution :**  You need to provide the Directory path to the `Directory.Exists()` method.

From MSDN : [Directory.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Determines whether the given path refers to an existing directory on
>   disk.

Replace This:

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:/Content/save/map.png"))
```

With This:

```
if (System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:/Content/save"))
```